# Create .Dirname in Windows

Tags: eclipse, windows

Trying to manage Eclipse workspace. How to create directory named `.Dirname` in `Windows 8`? Currently I'm getting strange message during this operation:

```
Rename
You must type a file name.
[OK]
```

Comment: How are you creating the directory?

Comment: Is this a Windows command prompt you are using? You should always use Eclipse itself to create directories and files in the workspace.